# Balancing of a binary search tree. Not working?

Tags: c++17, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

## AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

==30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffca44eafe8 (pc 0x00000034586e bp 0x7ffca44eb010 sp 0x7ffca44eaff0 T0)
==30==ABORTING

```
// counting nodes as height of tree
    int height(TreeNode* root) 
    {
        if(root == NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return max(height(root->left),height(root->right)) + 1;
    }
    
    TreeNode* LLRotation(TreeNode* p)
    {
        TreeNode* q = p->left;
        q->right = p;
        
        return q;
    }
    
    TreeNode* LRRotation(TreeNode* p)
    {
        TreeNode* q = p->left;
        TreeNode* r = q->right;
        
        r->right = p;
        r->left = q;
        return r;
    }
    
    TreeNode* RRRotation(TreeNode* p)
    {
        TreeNode* q = p->right;
        q->left = p;
        return q;
    }
        
    TreeNode* RLRotation(TreeNode* p)
    {
        TreeNode* q = p->right;
        TreeNode* r = q->left;
        
        r->left = p;
        r->right = q;
        return r;
    }
    
    TreeNode* balanceBST(TreeNode* root) {
        
        if(root == NULL)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        
        root->left = balanceBST(root->left);
        root->right = balanceBST(root->right);
        if(root->left != NULL || root->right != NULL)
        {
        if(abs(height(root->left) - height(root->right)) > 1)
        {
            if(height(root->left) - height(root->right) == 2)
            {
                if(height(root->left->left) - height(root->left->right) == 1)
                {
                    return LLRotation(root);
                }
                else {
                    return LRRotation(root);
                }
            }
            
            if(height(root->left) - height(root->right) == -2)
            {
                if(height(root->right->left) - height(root->right->right) == -1)
                {
                    return RRRotation(root);
                }
                else {
                    return RLRotation(root);
                }
            }
        }
        }
        return root;
```

## I was trying to balance a binary search tree but this code is not working i don't know why.
when i was degugging it shows segmentation fault in vs code and the below error message in leetcode.
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

==30==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow on address 0x7ffca44eafe8 (pc 0x00000034586e bp 0x7ffca44eb010 sp 0x7ffca44eaff0 T0)
==30==ABORTING

Idea for balancing:-
--start from bottom and then going to top
--check the balance factor of each node if it is not balanced then apply appropriate rotations
as we do in avl tree.
can anyone find the error in this code?

Comment: How deep is the tree you are testing with? If it's deep enough, any simple recursion (e.g. your `height` implementation) may overflow the stack.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was trying for a tree of height 4(but max limit of no. of nodes is 10^4).Can you suggest me what is the way of avoiding this?(ex - Input: root = [1,null,2,null,3,null,4,null,null])